# How to set the order of window?

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

I am looking for API to set order of window on OSX. Something like system does when we click on different windows of same application. API which system uses to set application's windows order or update the order.

Thank you

Comment: Windows of your own app, or any window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a public API to set the window order system-wide, but folks have reverse-engineered CoreGraphics' private calls. Look here for CGSPrivate.h and `CGSOrderWindow` might be what you need.

http://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h

As folks insist that I mention lately, using private APIs means you can't participate in the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you're trying to do. If you're trying to make some windows appear over/below others permanently, use [NSWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `-setLevel:`. If you're temporarily trying to bring a specific window to the front, use something like `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:`.